# Validating Jenkinsfiles within a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

The docs state to verify a Jenkinsfile you can do as follows

```
Linting via HTTP POST using curl
# curl (REST API)
# Assuming "anonymous read access" has been enabled on your Jenkins instance.
# JENKINS_URL=[root URL of Jenkins controller]
# JENKINS_CRUMB is needed if your Jenkins controller has CRSF protection enabled as it should
JENKINS_CRUMB=`curl "$JENKINS_URL/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,\":\",//crumb)"`
curl -X POST -H $JENKINS_CRUMB -F "jenkinsfile=<Jenkinsfile" $JENKINS_URL/pipeline-model-converter/validate
```

At the moment I am just trying to get the crumb. I am trying to do this programmatically in a pipeline, however issuing the curl command throws an error every time. `script.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

I have tried escaping the `(` character but that is a different error, it works without the xpath extension but it would be cleaner to include this. I have tried to use jenkins  Snippet Generator and when I plug in the command it gives `response = sh returnStdout: true, script: '''curl -s $JENKINS_URL/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,\\":\\",//crumb) '''`. However running this also gives an error.